# WiFi not working on Lubuntu 18.10 running on a 2008 imac with 1gb DDR2 RAM

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, mac

I wiped a 2008 imac and installed Lubuntu 18.10. My WiFi network doesn't show up although i have tried many things. It has a Broadcom BCM94321MC WiFi card and Ethernet works fine. when i run rfkill it only shows Bluetooth. I don't know much in terminal so please bear with me. TIA

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) may help you.

Comment: I tried that... It didn't work.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work? Edit the question with what you tried.